# Is it possible to avoid unnecessary injection in parent class?

Tags: android, dagger-2

Given the following example:

```
class CustomView extends View {
    @Inject
    SomeObject mObject;

    @Override
    protected void onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate();
        getApplicationComponent().inject(this);
    }
}

class SecondaryCustomView extends CustomView {
    @Inject
    AnotherObject mAnotherObject;

    @Override
    protected void onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate();
        getApplicationComponent().inject(this);
    }
}
```

Both custom views may be used on a layout independently. The second is just a bit more specialized than the first one.

As you can see, both have fields to inject and both need to call inject(). The problem is that when SecondaryCustomView calls its inject(), Dagger injects an instance of AnotherObject and an instance of SomeObject. After the call to super.onFinishInflate(), it creates a second instance of SomeObject. This is not a problem per se, but we are at least creating unnecessary objects.

Is there a way to avoid this? Some way to tell Dagger that a child class has been injected, so ignore the parent injection?

As an example, the Component looks like this:

```
@Component(...)
public interface AppComponent {
    void inject(CustomView);
    void inject(SecondaryCustomView);
}
```

Comment: Can you also post your component's interface?

Comment: This is just an example. If you want to know the scope of the injected objects, please consider that a new instance will be created for every injection.

Comment: I'm interested what is the type of the `this` in the interface method signature.

Comment: Ok. Added the component.

Comment: why not just remove onFinishInflate from your SecondaryCustomView? It's already being called, and it matches that of its super exactly. You're calling inject twice.

Comment: This isn't really a Dagger question.  If `CustomView` has properties that `SecondaryCustomView` should not have, then `SecondaryCustomView` should not extend `CustomView` in the first place.

Comment: @ootinii, this is just sample code. real code would have more content in onFInishInflate. Let's just assume both are needed.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede SecondaryCustomView should have all properties from CustomView. The problem here is that mObject will get injected twice and I would like to avoid that.

Comment: In the case of onFinishInflate also being needed in the extending class, I wouldn't think you'd need to call inject in the extending class, knowing it gets called in the super.

Comment: @ootinii yes it is needed. Dagger does not inject the child objects if we use injection on parent only. however it injects the parent objects if it is called from the child.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to do this in Dagger, but you can do it yourself.

To agree with and expand on your point in the comments:

> yes it is needed. Dagger does not inject the child objects if we use injection on parent only. however it injects the parent objects if it is called from the child.

That's correct, and noted in ["A note about covariance"](https://google.github.io/dagger//api/latest/dagger/Component.html#members-injection-methods): Though `inject(Foo)` can accept an instance of Foo or any of its subclasses, Dagger's a *compile-time* framework; `inject(Foo)` will not be generated to inject the fields belonging to arbitrary subclasses of Foo because, well, that's impossible to know at compile time. This can be a little surprising, particularly if your Component has both `inject(Foo)` and `inject(FooSubclass)` as you have for CustomView and SecondaryCustomView here: With names `injectCustomView` and `injectSecondaryCustomView` it would be obvious that only the former is callable from within Foo.

Aside from simply setting an `injectedAlready` boolean field as a flag, one technique is to create an overridable method, which does not call its superclass implementation:

```
class CustomView extends View {
    @Inject
    SomeObject mObject;

    @Override
    protected void onFinishInflate() {
        injectMe();
        super.onFinishInflate();
    }

    protected void injectMe() {
        getApplicationComponent().inject(this); // inject(CustomView);
    }
}

class SecondaryCustomView extends CustomView {
    @Inject
    AnotherObject mAnotherObject;

    @Override
    protected void onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate();
        // ...
    }

    /** Despite looking identical, the JVM can call the more-specific overload here. */
    @Override protected void injectMe() {
        getApplicationComponent().inject(this); // inject(SecondaryCustomView)
    }
}
```

If you're looking for a similar solution for Activity and Fragment classes, you can use [dagger.android](https://google.github.io/dagger/android.html); the built-in mechanism there uses the runtime type of the class to dynamically fetch the right AndroidInjector from a Map. However, that solution doesn't support View at the moment, so this is as close as you can get for your specific case.

Comment: Nice solution! Thanks!